# Where should I store a TextView data source

Tags: android

I have an AutoCompleteTextView which works with a list of cities.
The list is long, and so I'm thinking where/how/if to store and/or cache it.

My initial thought was to get the list from my web service, but it's a long list with 1500+ rows.

Should I get it from the web service with each request? Get it once and cache it? Store it in strings.xml to begin with and make sure to keep the list up to date? (It doesn't change much anyway).

I'm new to Android and mobile programming in general. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they would not change frequently (How many times do new cites get created?) Its recommended you store them as a string resource.

```
<string-array name="cities">
 <item>One</>
 <item>Two</>
 <item>Three</>
</string-array>
```

You can retrieve the list anytime with

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way to make this list and the AutoCompleteTextView have two columns, one visible and one as a key? This will make submitting it back to the web service easier.

Comment: If you want to add additional data to the `ListView` that would not be displayed, you can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods but I recommend you keep track of selected items by getting the chosen city from the string array using the `rowId` of the selected row in the `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

If it's not going to change, store it in strings.xml. If it's going to change, get it, cache it, and update when ever you need to. I would suggest caching it in a sql database. Then you can use cursors and there's a whole bunch of classes that play super nicely with cursors.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to keep the list is in SharedSettings. When you application initializes, check with the web app for a new list, and update as necessary. Then save the response to a ShareSettings String.
here is an example of how to do this if your list is separated by "|" bar symbols:

```
autocomplete_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("application_preferences", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        String autocomplete_string = settings.getString("autocomplete_player_names", getResources().getString(R.string.add_players_default_autocomplete));
        String[] array = autocomplete_string.split("\\|");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String string = array[i];
            autocomplete_list.add(string); 
        }
```

and you can apply it to an edit text like so:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView input = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
        String[] array = new String[autocomplete_list.size()]; 
        autocomplete_list.toArray(array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array);
        input.setAdapter(adapter);
```